# Compact-Hausdorff space in general topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Why Is in general  topology every Compact-Hausdorff space normal? 
Is every normal space Compact-Hausdorff space?

Comment: Hint: do it in two steps. First prove that a compact Hausdorff space is regular. Then prove that a compact regular space is normal.

Comment: You'll also need that every closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Comment: Normal does not imply compact. Every metric space is normal, but not necessarily compact. If a normal space is $T_1$ then it is also Hausdorff.

Comment: Suppose Property P is "Whenever $A, B$ are closed and disjoint, there are disjoint  open $A',B'$ with $A \subset A'$ and $B\subset B' \;$"... Most books define a normal space  as a $T_1$ space with Property P... This def'n implies that a normal space is $T_2$ (Hausdorff)... In "General Topology" by R. Engelking, a space with Property P but not necessarily $T_1$ is called pseudo-normal.... $\Bbb R$ is a normal, non-compact space.

Answer (score 1):

This is classic and in most text books. First show that $X$ is regular:

Let $A$ be closed in $X$ and $p \notin A$. For each $a \in A$, $a \neq p$ and so Hausdorffness gives us open sets $U_a$ and $V_a$ such that

$$a \in U_a, p \in V_a \text{ and } U_a \cap V_a = \emptyset\tag{1}$$

Then $\{U_a: a \in A\}$ is an open cover of $A$, which is compact too (being closed in $X$) and so there are finitely many $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ such that $$A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{a_i}$$

and define $U= \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{a_i}$, an open neighbourhood of $A$ and $V= \bigcap_{i=1}^n V_{a_i}$, which is an open (because we have a finite intersection) neighbourhood of $p$. And $U \cap V = \emptyset$, or otherwise $x \in U \cap V$ implies there is some $1 \le i \le n$ with $x \in U_{a_i}$ but then $x \in V \subseteq V_{a_i}$ as well, contradicting $(1)$. So we have disjoint neighbourhoods for a closed $A$ and a point not in $A$.

For two disjoint closed sets $A$ and $B$ we apply the regularity we just proved to $A$ and each $b \in B$ and find a finite subcover for $B$ and their union and the corresponding intersection of open neighbourhoods of $A$ can be shown very similarly to be disjoint neighbourhoods of $A$ and $B$ again.

Comment: My edit was for a trivial typo (yo=to) in the last line.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Why did you use interesction for V when you used the union for U?

Comment: @JJ otherwise the proof of disjointness doesn’t work.